# Linux + iptables fallback

Tags: linux, rhel, iptables

I want to enable the routing VIA tcp from port 770 to port 7714

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 770 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 7714
```

.

so I get the following:

```
iptables --table nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:shell redir ports 7714

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

please advice how to fallback ( as was before we run this command )  what is the command syntax for fallback  ?

Answer (score 1):

The changes to iptables can't be rolled back one by one: you have to reset all the rules and re-apply the ones you need. In your case, you seem to have a clean firewall by default, so all you need to do is:

```
sudo iptables --table nat ---flush
```

This will remove all the rules from the "nat" table.